# SQL::Abstract Type Cast Column

Tags: postgresql, perl, mojolicious, sql-abstract

Using `SQL::Abstract` I need to type cast an IP column to `TEXT` in order to be able to search using `LIKE`.

I only found a "hacky" way to achieve it with:

```perl
where( { ip => { '::TEXT LIKE' => $myParameter } } )
```

Which generates

```perl
WHERE ( "ip" ::TEXT LIKE ? )
```

Question is: Is there a less hacky or official way to achieve this?

Questions are not:

- Will the performance be poor?
- Should I use a `TEXT` column instead of an `IP` column?
- Are searches using CIDR a better alternative

Comment: Your suggestion should probably have a string ref, or you might run into trouble with quoting column names. `{ \'::TEXT LIKE' => $foo }`

Comment: No. String refs don't work as comparators. It would just give: `WHERE ( "ip" SCALAR(0X560F0B7AD918) ? )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in `Mojo::Pg` which adds a `quote_char` of `"` to the SQL::Abstract object.

When I set this to the empty string, this will work as expected:

```perl
where( { 'ip::TEXT' => { 'LIKE' => $myParameter } } )
```

But, to be complete, I had to use

```perl
where( { 'host(ip)' => { 'LIKE' => $myParameter } } )
```

because `::TEXT` will give the IP with an appended `/32`.

Answer (score -1):

I think you mix a lot of things in your question. You make it sound like it is an `SQL::Abstract` issue, when your real issue is with the underlying SQL itself.

First of all, I would personally avoid using `SQL::Abstract` in most cases (it is sometimes VERY slow to create complex queries and you can't be sure of its output) and definitely in cases like this where you want something non-standard.

So, moving on, I am not sure what you mean by `IP` type, from your postgres tag and the mention of `CIDR` I suspect you mean the `inet` type? If so, the equivalent of `LIKE` is to use subnet masks, which is basically the whole reason to use `inet` instead of a text/varchar field. For `192.168.*` for example you would do something like below using the subnet slash notation:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE ip << inet '192.168.0.0/16'
```

If you don't want to treat IPs as actual IPs and take advantage of things like above, but instead you want to treat them like text (e.g. you want to search `192.16%` with that producing `192.168.*` results but along with `192.16.*` etc which is not done with subnet masks), then you either use a text type in the first place, or as you said convert on the fly to use `LIKE` directly:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE TEXT(ip) LIKE '192.168.%'
```

There is a performance penalty over using the subnet masks, but whether that may be an issue depends on your data of course.

Note `cidr` works similar to `inet`, it won't help you with a `LIKE`.